# Windows 10 "does not see" a file on CD burned on Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, cd

Ubuntu 16.06: I burn a data file to a regular CD by Basero Disc burner. 
I can see and copy the file if I insert the CD in Win-7, but in Win-10  the CD is empty!

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated your computer recently... "KB4013429" or other update could be the culprit. You might have a look at your Device Manager and roll back the driver of the CD/DVD. Or update the driver from the device manufactures website.

You may want a look at this page:
https://www.easeus.com/backup-utility/cd-dvd-missing-or-not-showing-up-in-windows-10.html

"KB4013429" reference

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-windvd/reliability-update-is-available-for-windows-dvd/32f6406f-060c-4e51-a8ec-be5f80622d93?page=2

Comment: The update you linked to was released on March 20, 2017.  The patch in question does not apply to the version of Windows 10 the author is using.  Answers should contained all relevant information required to answer the question, information from external sites, should be quoted and cited.